# Relative File Path m3u

Tags: playlists

I want a playlist to refer to a relative file path, so I can copy it to my mobile phone or any future drive and it will still work.

The playlist is located in `/home/gratis/Music/Hip-Hop/50 Cent/The Very Best Of 50 Cent/11 - Patiently Waiting (ft. Eminem).m3u`, and its entries are:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:286,Eminem - Patiently Waiting (ft. 50 Cent)
/home/gratis/Music/Hip-Hop/Eminem/The EMINEM Anthology/074 - Patiently Waiting (ft. 50 Cent).opus
```

So, that's basically two directories up from where it's located -> Eminem -> The EMINEM Anthology -> music file.

I replaced `/home/gratis` with `..`, and tried Mark Kirby's suggestion (replacing `/home/gratis` with `~`), but neither of those attempts worked. How can I make these paths relative and/or portable?

Comment: Error for case 1:

File reading failed:
VLC could not open the file "/home/gratis/Music/Hip-Hop/50 Cent/The Very Best Of 50 Cent/../Music/Hip-Hop/Eminem/The EMINEM Anthology/074 - Patiently Waiting (ft. 50 Cent).opus" (No such file or directory).
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///home/gratis/Music/Hip-Hop/50%20Cent/The%20Very%20Best%20Of%2050%20Cent/..%2FMusic%2FHip-Hop%2FEminem%2FThe%20EMINEM%20Anthology%2F074%20-%20Patiently%20Waiting%20%28ft.%2050%20Cent%29.opus'. Check the log for details.

Error Case 2:

Comment: File reading failed:
VLC could not open the file "/home/gratis/Music/Hip-Hop/50 Cent/The Very Best Of 50 Cent/~/Music/Hip-Hop/Eminem/The EMINEM Anthology/074 - Patiently Waiting (ft. 50 Cent).opus" (No such file or directory).
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///home/gratis/Music/Hip-Hop/50%20Cent/The%20Very%20Best%20Of%2050%20Cent/~%2FMusic%2FHip-Hop%2FEminem%2FThe%20EMINEM%20Anthology%2F074%20-%20Patiently%20Waiting%20%28ft.%2050%20Cent%29.opus'. Check the log for details.

Comment: `~` is just a synonym for `$HOME` which is a variable for `/home/username` so a absolute path remains... this just works for other users with the same paths.

Comment: Thats what VLC does. It is "only once" in the playlist entry.
I remember it was something like ../, so I'm confused that doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for a relative path it is interesting where the playlist is located. --> the paths are relative... relative to what? for sure the playlist! ;-)

- for example the easiest is, everything is located in the same folder... then just delete the complete paths except the filenames and that's it: `track.flac`
- or lets assume a sampler with more than one disc in sub-folders: `disc1/track.flac`
- or the other way round; the playlist is located in a sub-folder: `../track.flac` --> `../` stands for one folder up.
- and the combination; a sampler with more discs and also playlists in different sub-folders: `../disk1/track.flac`

**the difference for absolute or relative paths are just the leading `/`!**

---

so... to combine all them together for your case, the correct relative path would be `../../Eminem/The EMINEM Anthology/074 - Patiently Waiting (ft. 50 Cent).opus` (if i'm right). ;-)

--> but keep in mind changing the folder structure will in most cases also mess up relative playlists, except just renaming the playlist-folder(s).

Comment: Hey, the point is to have one music file, that is playable in both Best-Of-Compilations.
I tried: "Music/Hip-Hop/Eminem/The EMINEM Anthology/074 - Patiently Waiting (ft. 50 Cent).opus" in the third line of the m3u file, but that would only work, if the playlist was in /home/gratis, right?

Comment: @MarkusGratis: yes, but this 4 folders in the playlist must never be changed or even renamed to keep the playlist working! - IMHO the best for relative paths is to keep them as short as possible... (and absolute playlists are anyway useless).

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that. But how to do it?

With the playlist in /50 Cent/The Best of 50 Cent/ that is...

Comment: @MarkusGratis: please read the **complete** answer careful. - i added a second part for your concrete case, so you only have to copy&paste. - if it isn't working please post, what isn't working, the error-message, etc...

Comment: I'm sorry, I only saw the second part just now. Thank you so much! That works ;)